# How can i get center of a cluster? Data points

Tags: math, cluster-analysis, hierarchical-clustering, centroid

Hello assume that i have the following variables inside single cluster

```
1.1 0 1.9
0 0 1.3
0.6 0.6 0.6
```

Now how can i find centroid of this cluster?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The centroid is the **arithmetic mean**.

More precisely, it is the means in each attribute, concatenated into a new vector.